# Can Launch4J be set so that the exe files it creates cannot show its contents through zip/egg/rar file when right click on/ open with it?

Tags: java, zip, egg, rar, launch4j

Launch4J is a jar to exe converter. I used Launch4J to convert jar to exe but when I right click on that exe file Launch4J created, it shows the contents in the jar file (class, etc files) from which it was made from when I right click on that exe file. Any way to disable that and disable showing its contents when opened using zip/rar/egg/jar?

Comment: *"Any way to disable that and disable showing its contents when opened using zip/rar/egg/jar(?)"*  a) Nobody wants to steal your app.  b) If they did, nothing would stop them.  c) If the app. was killer but the code hidden behind a web interface or such, it would be a simple but tedious matter to get testers to describe the inputs and outputs, designers to design code to do that, and programmers to write it.  That is legal in most countries.

Answer (score 2):

This is a pointless endeavor. It is very easy to extract class files from a running JVM. Hiding them in the executable is like making your windows secure but leaving your door open. Using an obfuscator is your only chance to make it harder to reverse engineer your implementation.

Answer (score 2):

1. Launch4J Really not making  normal EXE files. It making self-extracting archive (SFX).
   when click a exe file(made by Launch4J) it extract itself to your jre directory then execute the applications main jar file.

   **So they must be Extractable. You can't change them. If you do they will not work.**
2. If you interesting to  understand this process  Please read this (This will explain how we manually create a SFX file.)
   http://mark.koli.ch/2009/10/bundle-java-the-jre-and-launch-a-java-app-with-7zip-sfx.html
3. Here is a SFX file(it is an exe) made manually using 7 zip.
   http://mark.koli.ch/2009/10/26/7zipsfx-launch-java-example-exe.zip

Thank you.